# Sass Map (scss map-get) use in other scss import

Tags: sass

i have the index.scss that I've import login.scss , my question is how do map-get the color from index.scss ?

index.scss

```
@import "./style/login";

    $colors: (
        primary : #005DFF,
        accent : #FFF6BB
    );
```

this is what i done but i receive an error :
"File to import not found or unreadable: ./style/login."

login.scss

```
.bg { 
background-color: map-get($colors, primary );
}
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means the file isn't at the path you're pointing to. Is `index.scss` in the same directory as `login.scss`? If the file path is correct, it might be an issue with your build process. If you can, please add a screenshot of the folder where these files are, so we can see if the path is right.

Once you have that sorted, you'll need to edit this sass to make it work right. In `index.scss`, you need to declare your `$colors` map *above* your `@import login`. Otherwise, when `login` gets imported, it doesn't know what `$colors` is supposed to be.

Comment: it work just like you said i need to declare $colors above the import, thanks